# How do I upload an ISO to a newly built VMWare ESX 3.5 server?

Tags: vmware-esx

I have a newly built VMWare ESX Server that I would like to create a few Windows VMs on.  I'd like to transfer ISOs to the server to then mount them to install from.

How do I do this?  I assume there's a default set of FTP credentials or something of that nature...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via 'Browse Datastore' in the VSClient.

Answer (score 1):

If it's like ESXi, you open vsphere client, select and connect to the server.

Go to configuration tab.

click storage.

right click the data store

select browse data store.

select upload file and upload to where you want to store it. (icons near top of browse datastore for upload/download).