# How to connect to ESX Server Storage To Upload VM Images

Tags: storage, vmware-esx

I am trying to figure out how I can connect to an ESX server's storage system so that I can upload VM image files.  I am a windows user if that matters (i suspect it does).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the storage, is it internal drives, NAS, SAN

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/101535/how-do-i-upload-an-iso-to-a-newly-built-vmware-esx-3-5-server/101538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through the VMWare Infrastructure Client.

- Go to the Configuration -> Storage
  tab.
- Double click the Datastore you want
  to upload to.
- Click the Upload icon (looks like a little disk array with a green arrow pointing up)
- Follow the instructions from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use WinSCP, or Veeam's FastSCP -http://www.veeam.com/vmware-esxi-fastscp.html (works on ESX & ESXi)

I prefer FastSCP myself